# pull data from multiple sheets in google colab research

Tags: google-colaboratory, gspread

I can pull data from google spreadsheet by using

```
from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())    
worksheet = gc.open('RoutePlannerCumOptimizerInputSheet').sheet1
```

it does not take sheet name as parameter, my spreadsheet has **three sheets**, i can only access only one sheet. how to access other sheets and pull data in the same google spreadsheet. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `get_worksheet` function. Here's an [example from the gspread documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet):

Select worksheet by index. Worksheet indexes start from zero:

```
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
```

Or by title:

```
worksheet = sh.worksheet("January")
```

Or the most common case: Sheet1:

```
worksheet = sh.sheet1
```

To get a list of all worksheets:

```
worksheet_list = sh.worksheets()
```